# Нужна ли запятая в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация

**Занятия будут проводиться два раза в неделю во второй половине дня.**

Answer (score 2):

Занятия будут проводиться (как часто?)два раза в неделю (когда?)во второй половине дня.Это неоднородные обстоятельства, они отвечают на разные вопросы и означают одно - образ действия, другое - время. Запятой нет, если только автор не имеет в виду пояснение.